# Logging local variable values with AspectJ

Tags: logging, aspectj, aop

I heard a lot of great things about how AOP could help modularize things like logging, but now as I am trying to implement this, I am finding AspectJ is very limited.

Not only is it sometimes impossible to add logging to the correct lines, but accessing local variable values seems very difficult. You have to make sure that variable is either returned by a method or used as arguments to a method.

**The simple fact that the logging is outside of the scope of the code being logged is a severe limitation.**

Is there a better approach to accessing local variable values for the purpose of logging them?

For example, I have some code that maintains a counter, and I want to log the value of that counter. The original code looked something like this:

```
int totalMoves = 0;

while(canMove()) {
    // ...
    totalMoves++;
}

Logger.log(totalMoves);
```

I can't find a *clean* way to move this logging code to an aspect. There's simply no way to access `totalMoves` as it is. It appears that my options are:

1. Make `totalMoves` a publicly accessible field (in opposition to information hiding and encapsulation)
2. Create a dummy function that does nothing but allow a "hook" for AspectJ (no better than just logging directly)
3. Make `totalMoves` a private field, but use reflection to access it (seems like a bad code smell; creates an unnecessary field and complicates access to the variable)

To be honest, I guess what I was expecting when looking into AOP was inserting code verbatim to remove cross cutting concerns. These limitations make me question if AspectJ is even worth using in the current context.

Is there anyway around this issue? Or am I approaching this the wrong way? In which case, how can I cleanly log local variables?

**TL;DR: Logging local variable values with AspectJ is a mess, how can I make it better?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has been asked many times before. The answer is no. AspectJ cannot intercept read/write operations on local variables, only on members. Besides, the JVM might optimise away some of your source code dealing with local variables under certain circumstances, but that is another topic.

Abusing AOP frameworks like that would not a good idea anyway, even if it was possible. They are made for decorating classes with additional functionality or intercepting some actions accessible from outside, not for hacking local state. What does it say about your application design if an aspect needs to know local variable names?

As for the three options you are mentioning, they are not the only ones you have. You can also make `totalMoves` a private field and provide a getter and/or a setter if that makes sense. Furthermore, even if you decide not to use getter/setter, you can still use a [privileged aspect](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-aspects.html#aspect-privilege) which is able to access private or protected fields in combination with [`get|set()` pointcuts](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-pointcuts.html#d0e5231).

Feel free to ask if you do not understand this answer after reading the provided links.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It appears that aspects is not a good choice for the type of logging I'm trying to do.

Comment: What you are trying to do rather sounds like debugging or like classes and methods which are not black boxes (anti OOP). Have you tried a debugger, maybe even an advanced recording tool like Chronon? I cannot imagine that you want to slow down your production code by permanently adding this kind of low level logging outside of a debugging mode. Anyway, if you do, try a byte code instumentation tool like ASM. I recommend to refactor your application design instead, though.

Comment: it's very close to debugging. This is for a simulation system that has to make numerous calculations. Some types of calculations are logged. When something goes wrong, there's often many numbers to check, so we print them to logs. Also useful in easily detecting unexpected values. Eg, the mean starting income of all agents should be pretty similar each run.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to refactor that chunk of your code and extract a method out of it and add an aspect that logs its return value:

```
@Log
private int totalMoves() {
    int totalMoves = 0;

    while(canMove()) {
        // ...
        totalMoves++;
    }

    return totalMoves;
}
```